# How do I convert a string into an HTTP Response in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, httpresponse, httpresponsemessage

```
{
    "AdditionalProcessCardSwipeResponseData": null,
    "CustomerTransactionID": "",
    "ProcessCardSwipeOutputs": [
        {
            "AdditionalProcessCardSwipeResponseData": null,
            "CardSwipeOutput": {
                "AdditionalOutputData": [
                    {
                        "key": "CardType",
                        "value": "VISA"
                    }
                ],
                "CardID": "abcdefghijk",
                "IsReplay": false,
                "MagnePrintScore": 0.12345,
                "PanLast4": "1234"
            },
            "CustomerTransactionID": "",
            "DecryptForwardFaultException": null,
            "MagTranID": "2c3b08e9-b628-4f3c-a8ad-1ac1d57c1698",
            "PayloadResponse": "HTTP\/1.1 200 OKPragma: no-cache\u000aX-OPNET-Transaction-Trace: a2_8bfb4474-c9fb-4257-b914-8411770544e4-22192-26834262\u000aAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\u000aAccess-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with,cache-control,content-type,origin,method,SOAPAction\u000aAccess-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,OPTIONS,POST,GET\u000aAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\u000aStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000\u000aX-Cnection: close\u000aContent-Length: 328\u000aCache-Control: no-store\u000aContent-Type: application\/json; charset=utf-8\u000aDate: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 16:05:35 GMT\u000a\u000a&{\"messages\":{\"resultCode\":\"Error\",\"message\":[{\"code\":\"E00003\",\"text\":\"The 'AnetApi\/xml\/v1\/schema\/AnetApiSchema.xsd:customerProfileId' element is invalid - The value &#39;customer_profile_id&#39; is invalid according to its datatype 'AnetApi\/xml\/v1\/schema\/AnetApiSchema.xsd:numericString' - The Pattern constraint failed.\"}]}}",
            "PayloadToken": "ADFASDFASDFASDFASDFASFADSFF",
            "TransactionUTCTimestamp": "2019-12-26 16:05:35Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I convert the string returned for "PayloadResponse" to a HTTPResponse? I've tried the following but am not able to retrieve the body of the response:

```
var response = JObject.Parse(await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var payloadResponse = response["ProcessCardSwipeOutputs"][0]["PayloadResponse"];


var msg = new HttpResponseMessage
{
   Content = new StringContent(payloadResponse.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
```

This is the content of the PayloadResponse I want to convert to an HttpResponse so that I can parse out the response body in a clean way:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OKPragma: no-cache
X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace: a2_cadac737-0b60-45f5-9d5a-4d540c0975a0-7760-47076038
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with,cache-control,content-type,origin,method,SOAPAction
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,OPTIONS,POST,GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Cnection: close
Content-Length: 530
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu,
26 Dec 2019 21: 46: 56 GMT

&{
    "customerProfileId": "45345345345",
    "customerPaymentProfileId": "123123123",
    "validationDirectResponse": "1,1,1,(TESTMODE) This transaction has been approved.,000000,P,0,none,Test transaction for ValidateCustomerPaymentProfile.,1.00,CC,auth_only,none,John,Doe,,2020 Vision St,Somewhere,CA,90028,USA,,,email@example.com,,,,,,,,,0.00,0.00,0.00,FALSE,none,,,,,,,,,,,,,,XXXX1234,Visa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
    "messages": {
        "resultCode": "Error",
        "message": [
            {
                "code": "E00039",
                "text": "A duplicate customer payment profile already exists."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why that would ever be an appropriate request body, but that aside, what problem are you having?

Comment: Please edit your question's tags to indicate whether you're using .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Comment: You would likely have to parse it into a response object first.

Comment: @Crowcoder I've edited my question to make it more clear. I think I need to convert the string to an HttpResponse, is that correct @yaakov?

Comment: Yes, you will need to parse the `PayloadResponse` to extract the status code, etc. and then construct a `HttpResponseMessage` with those values. .NET Framework has no support for sending raw HTTP responses, it is possible in .NET Core but quite convoluted: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ee7c4b2a668cdc17dcc378bb389aac64

Comment: Thanks @IanKemp. I really just want to get to the json part of the response and thought .NET might have an easy way to convert this to an HttpMessage. Since it doesn't, I will parse the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to "*parse out the response body in a clean way*".

You are trying to convert this to an `HttpResponseMessage` because you think that will line everything up for you. This is a distraction, it makes it sound like you want to create a response and forward it on, but all you really want is the payload to be parsed into a usable format.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

To parse out that payload you can split that string on the newline character (`/u000a`), remove the extraneous `&` and parse the json.

```
var splitResponse = payloadResponse.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\u000a' });

string body = splitResponse.Last().Substring(1);

JObject job = JObject.Parse(body);

// example
Console.WriteLine(job["messages"]["message"][0]["text"]);
```

I did not provide classes that you can deserialize this json into because it is an error message and I assume you won't always be dealing with an error. A success response would probably be a different schema. I can't know how to design classes for this from the information you have provided but maybe working with the `JObject` is adequate.

Comment: Yes, ultimately I want to get to the json and was thinking .NET might have a way to do this easily since the string is a valid HttpResponse. Your suggestion will work and I can easily handle the json with JObject.